# Get status of scanner zebra se2707

Tags: c#, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to read the status of the zebra scanner parameters, I'm using `*.ExecCommand (opcode, ref inXML, out outXML, out status);` and I get the image above.
I'm not sure if those are the data I want, and if they are like knowing what state they correspond to, like for example if the printer is connected, beeper / LED status and all the states that I have are possible to monitor.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! I see you refer to an image, but I don't see any: could you please edit your question to explain what you're referring to? That will help people understand your question ;)
I added the c# tag to this question so that it has more visibility ;)

Comment: Did you look at the developers guide? https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/software/sdk-windows_devguide_en.pdf.  The status codes are on page 3-42

Comment: Ok. No puedo poner imagenes todavia, mando el opcode 5000 attr_getall. Outxml me da una lista de atributos pero no me indica su valor ni su nombre que como si utilizaras attr_get el cual nos da el attributo id valor nombre.                 Y yo lo q quiero es leer todos los atributos y valores de estado del escaner